# std::vector operator==: value or reference comparison?

Tags: c++, vector

So, I was trying to come up with a solution for [When does x==x+2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/when-does-x-x2) in C++ on codegolf, and came up with this snippet only to realize that I don't know how it works. I'm not sure why both of these conditions evaluate to true.

Does anyone know if the line labeled `line:` is true because x==&x or because x+2 is evaluated before the left-hand side of ==?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int>& operator+ ( std::vector<int> &v, int val )
{
    v.push_back(val);
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x;
    std::vector<int> y = x + 2; // y is a copy of x, and x is [2]

    // how are both of these are true?
    std::cout << (x==y) << "\n";    // value comparison [2]==[2]
line:
    std::cout << (x==x+2) << "\n";  // reference comparison? &x == &(x+2)

    // not sure if this is relevant
    std::cout << (x+2==x) << "\n";  // also true

    return 0;
}
```

It seems--since vectors appear to be compared by value--that if x were evaluated before x+2, then x wouldn't be equal to x+2 (by value). I'm probably missing something obvious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Totally does. gcc 4.5.3.

Comment: Operator `+` should return by value and don't change input parameters, like this: `std::vector<int> operator+ ( const std::vector<int> &v, int val );`

Comment: I wonder if the standard allows 'false' to be returned here?

Comment: @KennyTM: No, the function call that modifies the vector is sequenced before the function call that does the comparison.

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes. You're not allowed to overload `operator+` for a library-defined type and a built-in type, so it's UB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the standard containers, `operator==` is overloaded as [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal). This in turn works on itera­tors and applies comparison by dereferncing, as in `*it1 == *it2`. Therefore, no copies are required.

The expression `x == x + 2` is the same as `operator==(x, x + 2)`. Both operands are evaluated before the function call, and since `x + 2` modifies `x`, both operands are the same. Thus the equality holds.

The surprise is the result of your unconventional design choice in overloading the `+`-operator. This is ge­ne­rally poor practice and a taboo in any collaborative project. If you absolutely must overload opera­tors, then only if they behave as expected, follow established semantics and are not surprising. The usu­al behaviour of the `+`-operator is to return a new object, by value, and leave the operand unaffected. Like so:

```
std::vector<int> operator+(std::vector<int> v, int n)
{
    v.push_back(n);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Re: poor practice. For sure--the whole point was to make `x+2==x` for a silly coding puzzle. Re: std::equal. The more I learn about C++, the more I think there's an `<algorithm>` for everything I would ever try to write. ;) Great info. Thanks.

Comment: @NathanAndrewMullenax: I understand... it's certainly a nifty solution to the puzzle. I would probably have gone for a class that implements modular arithmetic :-)

Answer (score 4):

[std::vector's equality comparison](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) performs a lexicographical compare that checks that the size of `lhs` and `rhs` are the same, and then compares element by element.

The problem with your code is that you are assigning `x+2` to `y`, and your addition operator is modifying the `lhs`, acting like a `+=` operator.

Here:

```
std::vector<int> y = x + 2;
```

this modifies `x`, and copy assigns `y` from `x`. A well behaved `operator+` would be something like

```
std::vector<int> operator+ ( std::vector<int> v, int val )
{
    v.push_back(val);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I know, it's appending a single int to a vector and then returning a reference to the same vector. Is this not the case?

Comment: @NathanAndrewMullenax yep, totally sure. You modify `x` in your operator.

Comment: @NathanAndrewMullenax: It's like saying (if `a` and `b` are `int`s) `b = (a += 2);`. Both `a` and `b` will have the same result at the end.

Comment: Right, I think we're in agreement on that much. Hence the code comment.

Comment: I meant, 'are you sure?' in the sense of, 'are you sure I don't understand what my overloaded operator is doing?'

Comment: @NathanAndrewMullenax I meant I am sure about the behaviour of your `+` operator. Given an understanding of that, plus the link to the vector equality operator documentation, there is no mystery in the behaviour you observe.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion arises from the unconventional definition of `+`. Normally, it would return a modified copy of its argument, leaving the argument itself unchanged. Since the operator acts more like `+=`, modifying its argument and returning a reference to it, this is roughly equivalent to:

```
x.push_back(2), x == x
```

comparing the modified vector to itself.

C++ always compares values, never references; if you want a reference comparison, then you must explicitly compare addresses, `&x == &y`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector::operator==()` is (usually?) a function, and this is a sequence point in C++03, which means that it needs to fully evaluate all of it's parameters before it can be called.

Both parameters resolve to the same reference (vector x), so it is only natural that it would evaluate to true.

This is because that operator+ never creates a new object, it just modifies one.

It is, in fact, equivalent to this code:

```
std::vector<int> x;
x.push_back(2);
std::cout << (x==x) << "\n"; // this is no surprise
```

Comment: @juanchopanza I think itjax is saying that x and x+2 (rather than x and y) are both evaluated before they are passed as const references to the == operator, which is true because == is a sequence point in C++. Makes sense to me.

Comment: That is to say, x+2==x+4 as well because all side effects are evaluated before == is called.